# Get values of a checked box list,one at a time with PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

Good Day to you.This is what I have been trying to do.

I have a php page where I have drop down list with options as lecturers and students.
Once I select any option, details regarding lecturers or students will be displayed in a div using ajax.
Code is as follows.(This will be called in onchange event of the drop down list with a javascript.

```
<?php
session_start();
require "configuration.php";
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

if($q==1)
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM temp_instructor_log";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th><u><B>NIC</u></B></th>
            <th><u><B>Name</u></B></th>
            <th><u><B>Email</u></B></th>
            </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>"?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="emplist[]" value="<?php echo $row['nic']?>">
        <?php echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nic'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['firstName'] ." ".$row['lastName']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['email']."</td>";    
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Its working and giving me the display with checkboxes at the very beginning.

```
<?php session_start();
require "configuration.php";
?>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

    <title>Manage courses</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php 

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
    {
        if (isset($_POST['btnAccept'])) 
        {
            $utype=$_POST['category'];
            $arr = $_POST['emplist'];



            foreach( $arr as $item)
             {
            echo $item . "</br>"; /* Will print 1,2 and 3 (mind newlines)*/
            }
```

First I tried to echo the values after checking some of the checkboxes.But it didnt work out.Your kind consideration given on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For one thing, there is no form element called/named `btnAccept` which your conditional statement is based on and dependant on. Where is that coming/taken from?

Comment: Just follow this demo and adjust it to your needs -- http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/03/loading-data-related-to-selected-drop.html

Comment: No i did not post that part.Pardon me for confusing you all.First code segment is the way how I create the check boxes dynamically.It is working properly.But I want to check them and and transfer the data to another table(only the checked,check boxes)